# NPAPI plugin on Mac - launch another process

Tags: c++, macos, npapi, browser-plugin

So - I have two main objectives for an NPAPI plugin I'm trying to create (using FireBreath).

1. Check to see if an application is installed
2. Launch the application (with arguments)

Both of these methods will be exposed to and called from the javascript on the page. I could obviously hard-code the expected path, etc, but that seems a little hacky to me. And by launching the application, it seems like the standard way in C++ is to fork() and one of the exec*() functions - but I'm concerned how this would work in a browser plugin. I've done a similar thing on Windows - which I used the registry for and then launched using CreateProcess().

My questions are:
What's the best way (in C++) to check for the existence of an application on a Mac?
What's the best way (in C++) to launch this application on a Mac in a way that doesn't require the plugin to wait for the new process to exit?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find and launch an application on the Mac (whether running in a plugin or an other context) without using Objective-C (which I'll assume is what you are getting at when you say C++; there aren't really C++ APIs for things on the Mac, just C and Objective-C) is [Launch Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html).